# SIGSEGV In System.MonoEnumInfo.get_enum_info

Tags: c#, linux, entity-framework, mono

I'm trying to run a C# app in Mono on Linux.  I'm using EF6, it has some types that are mapped to enums.  The first time my app queries the DB (VistaDB) I get the following stack trace (its actually much larger...)

```
at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.MonoEnumInfo.get_enum_info (System.Type,System.MonoEnumInfo&) <IL 0x0000e, 0xffffffff>
at System.MonoEnumInfo.GetInfo (System.Type,System.MonoEnumInfo&) [0x00076] in /build/buildd/mono-3.2.8+dfsg/mcs/class/corlib/System/Enum.cs:176
at System.Enum.GetNames (System.Type) [0x0002d] in /build/buildd/mono-3.2.8+dfsg/mcs/class/corlib/System/Enum.cs:334
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EnumType..ctor (System.Type) <IL 0x00056, 0x001eb>
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ClrEnumType..ctor (System.Type,string,string) <IL 0x00002, 0x00027>
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.OSpaceTypeFactory.TryCreateEnumType (System.Type,System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EnumType,System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmType&) <IL 0x00027, 0x0009f>
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.OSpaceTypeFactory.TryCreateType (System.Type,System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmType) <IL 0x0003b, 0x000eb>
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly () <IL 0x0006c, 0x0010c>
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load () <IL 0x00007, 0x0001f>
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.LoadAssemblies (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Reflection.Assembly>,System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemLoadingSessionData) <IL 0x00019, 0x00072>
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.LoadClosureAssemblies () <IL 0x00011, 0x00023>
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load () <IL 0x00013, 0x00031>
...
Native stacktrace:

mono() [0x4b73d8]
mono() [0x50f13b]
mono() [0x423d22]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340) [0x7fd7577c0340]
mono(mono_class_from_mono_type+0x6) [0x525736]
mono() [0x5428a4]
[0x41d0d6f3]
...
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Based on this I suspect there is a problem with Mono.  I'm running Ubuntu 14 with Mono 3.2.8 (installed using apt-get).  Has anyone else run into this?  If I remove the enum mappings from EF will that fix the problem?

**Update**

I tried running the same on my macbook running Mono 3.4, and I got the same error.  So I suspect it's a bug with Mono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to mono 3.6.1 and EF seems to be working well!  Looks like mono 3.2.8 does not work with EF 6 and vista db